# Как сделать что бы кнопка Логин находилась на одной линии с полями емейла и пароля?(картинка как нужно внутри)

Tags: html, css

```css
* {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;  
    height: calc(100vh - 16px);
    color: aliceblue;
}
form {
    width: 500px;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
    background: url(../images/bg_blue.png) no-repeat center/cover;
    padding: 45px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.514);
}
h1{
    font-size: 3em;
    margin: 0px 0px;
}
p{
    max-width: 380px;
    margin: 10px 0px 40px ;
}
.center{
    text-align: center;
}
.form-row {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
.half{
    width: 27%;
    
}
input{
    background-color: rgb(68, 105, 185);
    border: 1px solid rgb(12, 47, 124);
    color: aliceblue;
    margin-left: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
}
.fix{
    margin-left: -30px ;
    margin-top: 12px;
} 
.button{
    width: 100px;
    margin: 30px 0px 0px;
    background-color: rgb(72, 122, 228);
    color: aliceblue;
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    padding: 15px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
.checkbox, a{
    font-size: 12px;
}
a{
    margin-top: 2px;
    text-align: right;
}
.lokal{
    text-align: center;
}
input[type="submit"]{
    font-weight: 800;
}
input[type="submit"]:hover{
    background-color:  rgb(41, 82, 170);
}
input[type="submit"]:focus{
    background-color: rgb(7, 51, 145);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/aform.css">
</head>

<body>
    <form name="login" id="login">
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor veritafugiat illo, veniam contetur dicta.</p>
        <div class="center">
            <div class="">
                <label for="email">Email:</label><input type="email" placeholder="" value="" name="Email" id="email" required size="25">
            </div>
            <div class="fix">
                <label for="password">Password:</label><input type="password" placeholder="" value="" name="password" id="password" required size="25"> 
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <label class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" value='' title="Remember Me"> Remember Me </label>
            <a href="#" class="half">Forgor password?</a>
        </div>
        <div class="lokal"><input type="submit" value="LOGIN" class="button"></div>


    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Нужно что бы кнопка Логин находилась на одной линии с полями емейла и пароля. Как это сделать, помогите?[image: сама картинка]

Comment: Сверстать табличкой и не париться. )

Comment: по-хорошему, этот ужас надо переверстать. Но если вам так нравится, то сдвиньте кнопку влево с помощью отрицательного маргина.

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/YzQRxEE  так ?

Comment: @Инквизитор спасибо, а можно на ошибки указать, если нетрудно?

Comment: @Айболит спасибо, можно и так, я просто думал может какой-то еще способ есть

Comment: @Dwee, например, вы сдвигаете инпуты друг под друга за счет отрицательных маргинов у лейблов. Просто представьте себе, что вы поменяли у лейблов шрифт. или содержимое. вам придется снова двигать маргинами. При этом в разных браузерах может быть разный результат, т.к. округления при расчетах делаются по-разному.